# Are we instructed to re-roll or re-roll-off?

Tags: semantics

In the [Warhammer 40k Kill Team Core Manual](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Wh40k-Kill-Team-Rulebook-2018-eng) pg 20 it tells us how to deal with roll-offs:

> ## ROLL-OFFS
>
> Some rules instruct players to roll off. To do so, each player rolls a D6 (or 2D6 if there are more than two players), and whoever scores the highest wins the roll-off. In the case of a tie, those players re-roll their dice -- if the second and subsequent rolls are also tied keep on rolling until a winner is determined; this is the only time players can re-roll a re-roll.

The problem lies with the following sentence:

> In the case of a tie, those players **re-roll** their dice

I interpret it two ways. The first is what I think it is instructing us to do -- in the case of a tie you are using the re-roll to determine the position of just the tied players. However as we are being instructed to *re-roll* the dice not **re-roll-off**, it reads that these new results could overtake existing rolls.

Take the following situation:

> Person A rolls a: 5
>   Person B rolls a: 4
>   Person C rolls a: 4
>
> There is a tie, and so B and C re-roll. Resulting in:
>
> Person B rolls a: 6
>   Person C rolls a: 4

With the former interpretation the winning order is; A, B, C, as A won the round with the tie. However as it only specifies that you should re-roll, not re-roll-off, the winning sequence would be; B, A, C.

Which way are we being instructed to roll-off?

Comment: Substitute *contest* for *roll-off* and you'll get it. The roll-off is a contest and doesn't refer to specific die rolls. Each time two players each roll a die, that constitutes a roll-off. If six players roll, that's also a roll-off.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The set of rolls all together form a contest/roll-off. The individuals each roll, or if they have to roll again, they re-roll.

Comment: Hmm I understand the issue. I would say the text is ambiguous: it says to reroll, but 1.) it doesn't say who "those players" are; and 2.) in case only two out of a larger number of players must reroll, it doesn't say whether one of the rerollers must win even if both roll now a lower number than the non-rerolling players. // We would strictly read  "those players" as "players" or possibly "each player" (the previous mention of players), so all players should reroll. But, based on my experience with other games, I suspect this is not the intended interpretation, as you say.

Comment: By the way, it says "whoever scores the highest wins the roll-off". It doesn't say anything about a winning order other than that there should be one winner; so I would it read it thus: only the one person who wins the roll-off (with or without rerolls) wins; the ultimate order of the other rollers doesn't matter. So you would only do a reroll if the first place is tied, not if lower-ranking places are tied.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'm now confused about your question. Are you asking about what some things are called (as in your title) or about what the rules mean?

Comment: @Peilonrayz: Hmm, I see. Perhaps the rules aren't entirely worded in a consistent manner throughout the manual. At the very least, they are ambiguous and far from clear! The manual would benefit from an editor...

Comment: Believe it or not, there is a lexical problem with _re-roll-off_, which can lead to its being avoided. It turns out that a whole bunch of Latin prefixes like _re-, pre-,_ etc. can't co-occur with phrasal verbs. So you can _look over_ or _examine_ a book, and you can _re-examine_ it, but you can't *_re-look over_ the book. It seems to be the case that the particle fills much the same role as the prefix -- vague extension -- but that the phrasal verb is the Germanic way and the prefix is the Romance way.